# Using Cypress, How can I compare the 2 values from a form. I need to match if $5 is matching from both the screenshots. (Subtotal vs final total)

Tags: automation, cypress

Using Cypress, How can I compare the 2 values from a form. I need to match if $5 is matching from both the screenshots. (Subtotal vs final total)

**Subtotal**

[image: Subtotal]

**Final Total**

[image: Final Total]

Comment: @Nldhi J Posted my answer, please give a try

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `invoke('text')` method to get `sub-total` value and store to a variable, then same way to get the `total amount` into another variable and compare both.

*Note:* If there are any issues with `spaces` with resulting sub-total value and total amount, please use a javascript method to get rid of the spaces, maybe `trim()` is an option.

```js
it('Check Subtotal equal to Final total', () => {
  // write the test code till you are up to Create Your Invoice...
  cy.get('[formarrayname="item_list"] > div > .col-2 > .col-1.sub-total-label')
    .invoke('text')
    .then((text) => {
      const subTotal = text;
      cy.get('.total-wrapper.valid-amount label').invoke('text')
        .then((text1)=>{
          const finalTotal = text1;
          var trimFinal = finalTotal.replace('Total:','');
          expect(subTotal).to.eq(trimFinal );
        })
      })  
})
```

You could try getting the value directly using the this class: `.col-1.sub-total-label`

```js
cy.get('.col-1.sub-total-label').invoke('text)...
```